# boot time for 20.04 LTS is very high on Lenovo N200 4GBRAM 180HDD

Tags: boot, 20.04, lenovo, time

PC spec are:
'''
Linux krishna-3000-N200 5.4.0-42-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 10 00:24:02 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
'''
lshw for pC is below:

'''
description: Computer
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smp vsyscall32

*-core
description: Motherboard
physical id: 0
*-memory
description: System memory
physical id: 0
size: 4GiB
*-cpu
product: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T5450  @ 1.66GHz
vendor: Intel Corp.
physical id: 1
bus info: cpu@0
size: 1318MHz
capacity: 1667MHz
width: 64 bits

```
 *-pci
      description: Host bridge
      product: Mobile PM965/GM965/GL960 Memory Controller Hub
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 100
      bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
      version: 0c
      width: 32 bits
      clock: 33MHz
    *-display:0
         description: VGA compatible controller
         product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary)
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
         version: 0c
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
         configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
         resources: irq:16 memory:fc000000-fc0fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:1800(size=8) memory:c0000-dffff
    *-display:1 UNCLAIMED
         description: Display controller
         product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary)
         vendor: Intel Corporation
         physical id: 2.1
         bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
         version: 0c
         width: 64 bits
         clock: 33MHz
         capabilities: bus_master cap_list
         configuration: latency=0
         resources: memory:fc100000-fc1fffff
```

'''

below is the critical path output.

'''

```
graphical.target @1min 21.638s
└─multi-user.target @1min 21.636s
  └─snapd.seeded.service @52.716s +528ms
    └─snapd.service @31.105s +21.599s
      └─basic.target @30.277s
        └─sockets.target @30.277s
          └─snapd.socket @30.270s +6ms
            └─sysinit.target @30.123s
              └─snapd.apparmor.service @29.266s +856ms
                └─apparmor.service @27.535s +1.728s
                  └─local-fs.target @27.533s
                    └─run-snapd-ns-canonical\x2dlivepatch.mnt.mount @45.633s
                      └─run-snapd-ns.mount @43.622s
                        └─swap.target @27.011s
                          └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-44e357ef\x2dfd87\x2d4721\x2d8870\x2df8b1c14d9339.swap @26.939s +69ms
                            └─dev-disk-by\x2duuid-44e357ef\x2dfd87\x2d4721\x2d8870\x2df8b1c14d9339.device @26.936s
```

'''

please suggest if any way to decrease boot time from 2 min.

Comment: thanks for quick response. sudo blkd gives as below:                                 '''    /dev/sda2: UUID="44e357ef-fd87-4721-8870-f8b1c14d9339" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="2bc4995c-02"
/dev/sda1: UUID="56fedd71-673a-4f13-be23-3a259677a705" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="2bc4995c-01"
/dev/sda3: UUID="c13cb778-6e02-4170-81f2-51eb66ab0047" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="2bc4995c-03"

Comment: and gedit /etc/fstab gives:       UUID=56fedd71-673a-4f13-be23-3a259677a705 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda3 during installation
UUID=c13cb778-6e02-4170-81f2-51eb66ab0047 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda2 during installation
UUID=44e357ef-fd87-4721-8870-f8b1c14d9339 none            swap    sw              0       0